# Assumptions in the LSZ reduction formula

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

In Srednicki, Chapter 5, it is said that the LSZ reduction formula holds only under the assumptions 
$$ \langle 0|\phi(x)|0\rangle =0 \qquad\text{and} \qquad \langle k|\phi(x)|0\rangle =e^{-ikx}$$

I don't understand why the first assumption (and a related one discussed in the chapter) is necessary. It seems that the assumption follows from Lorentz invariance.

We know, using only the fact that $\phi(x)$ is a Lorentz scalar, that
$$ [P^{\mu},\phi(x)]=i\partial ^{\mu}\phi(x)$$

Then, we have
$$ a^{\dagger}(k)=-i\int d^3x \; e^{ikx}[-i\partial_0\phi(x)+\omega \phi(x)]$$

Therefore, 
\begin{equation}
[P^{\mu},a^{\dagger}(k)] = -i\int d^3x \; e^{ikx}[\partial_0\partial^{\mu}\phi(x)+i\omega \partial^{\mu}\phi(x)]\\
=\int d^3x \; e^{ikx}\partial^{\mu}[-i\partial_0\phi(x)+\omega \phi(x)]\\
=-\int d^3x \; \partial^{\mu}(e^{ikx})[-i\partial_0\phi(x)+\omega \phi(x)]\\
=-ik^{\mu}\int d^3x \; e^{ikx}[-i\partial_0\phi(x)+\omega \phi(x)]\\
=k^{\mu} a^{\dagger}(k)
\end{equation}

This shows that $a^{\dagger}(k)|0\rangle$ is now an eigenvector of $P^{\mu}$ of eigenvalue $k^{\mu}$. So we have:
$$ a^{\dagger}(k)|0\rangle = \lambda |k\rangle $$

It seems to me that it has two implications:

One is that
$$ \langle 0|a^{\dagger}(k)|0\rangle = 0$$
and hence
$$ \langle 0|a(k)|0\rangle = \overline{\langle 0|a^{\dagger}(k)|0\rangle}=0$$

Then, doesn't it imply
$$\langle 0 | \phi(x) | 0 \rangle = 0$$
only from the assumption that $\phi(x)$ is a Lorentz scalar? (Without any renormalization assumption)

The second consequence is that
$$ \langle k',n|a^{\dagger}(k)|0\rangle = 0$$
for any $k'\neq k$.

If so, why did Srednicki spend so much effort to prove that 
$$ \langle k',n|a_1^{\dagger}(t)|0\rangle \rightarrow 0\qquad \text{as}\qquad t\rightarrow \pm \infty$$

Comment: The LSZ formula is trivial for free field theories (as is the condition for zero vev, if you use that free field Fourier expansion). The conclusion should be interpreted by reminding oneself that the condition for zero vev may not be consistent with the original form of the full interacting field Lagrangian density.

Comment: Sorry but I am still confused. Here, I am deriving the formulas only from the assumption that the field is a Lorentz scalar, and hence the formula for commutator with momentum operators. It seems to follow from the above calculation that zero VEV holds regardless of the form of Lagrangian density, whether or not it has interaction, or counterterms. It does seem to contradict the fact that you get nonzero VEV without a Y\phi counterterm in \phi^3 theory, but where did the logic go wrong?